# why this error become (C2664 error c++ Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to modify an program.implemented in 2015 visual studio.  After opening the project in Visual Studio 2019 there are many errors of the type below.

> ```
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error C2664    'Model::Model(Model &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const > char [24]' to 'GLchar *' OpenGl  
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Message        Conversion from string literal loses const qualifier (see /Zc:strictStrings)   OpenGl
> ```

Error formed in that line:

```
// Create a GLFWwindow object that we can use for GLFW's functions
 GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow( WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", 
 nullptr, nullptr );

if ( nullptr == window )
{
    std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate( );

    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

glfwGetFramebufferSize( window, &SCREEN_WIDTH, &SCREEN_HEIGHT );

// Set the required callback functions
glfwSetKeyCallback( window, KeyCallback );
glfwSetCursorPosCallback( window, MouseCallback );

// GLFW Options
glfwSetInputMode( window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED );

// Set this to true so GLEW knows to use a modern approach to retrieving 
function pointers and extensions
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
// Initialize GLEW to setup the OpenGL Function pointers
if ( GLEW_OK != glewInit( ) )
{
    std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Define the viewport dimensions
glViewport( 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

// OpenGL options
glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

// Setup and compile our shaders
Shader shader( "res/shaders/modelLoading.vert", 
 "res/shaders/modelLoading.frag" );

// Load models
Model ourModel("res/models/nanosuit.obj");

// Draw in wireframe
//glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );

glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective( camera.GetZoom( ), ( float 
)SCREEN_WIDTH/( float )SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f );

// Game loop
while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
{
    // Set frame time
    GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime( );
    deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = currentFrame;

    // Check and call events
    glfwPollEvents( );
    DoMovement( );

    // Clear the colorbuffer
    glClearColor( 0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    shader.Use( );

    glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix( );
    glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( shader.Program, "projection" 
       ), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( projection ) );
     glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( shader.Program, "view" ), 
       1, 
    GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( view ) );

    // Draw the loaded model
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::translate( model, glm::vec3( 0.0f, -1.75f, 0.0f ) ); // 
  Translate it down a bit so it's at the center of the scene
    model = glm::scale( model, glm::vec3( 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f ) ); // It's a 
  bit too big for our scene, so scale it down
     glUniformMatrix4fv( glGetUniformLocation( shader.Program, "model" ), 
   1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr( model ) );
    ourModel.Draw( shader );

    // Swap the buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers( window );
}

glfwTerminate( );
return 0;
}

         // Moves/alters the camera positions based on user input
    void DoMovement( )
          {
// Camera controls
if ( keys[GLFW_KEY_W] || keys[GLFW_KEY_UP] )
{
    camera.ProcessKeyboard( FORWARD, deltaTime );
}

if ( keys[GLFW_KEY_S] || keys[GLFW_KEY_DOWN] )
{
    camera.ProcessKeyboard( BACKWARD, deltaTime );
}

if ( keys[GLFW_KEY_A] || keys[GLFW_KEY_LEFT] )
{
    camera.ProcessKeyboard( LEFT, deltaTime );
}

if ( keys[GLFW_KEY_D] || keys[GLFW_KEY_RIGHT] )
{
    camera.ProcessKeyboard( RIGHT, deltaTime );
    **strong text**  }
}

       // Is called whenever a key is pressed/released via GLFW
    void KeyCallback( GLFWwindow *window, int key, int scancode, int 
          action, int mode )
         {
if ( GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE == key && GLFW_PRESS == action )
{
    glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

if ( key >= 0 && key < 1024 )
{
    if ( action == GLFW_PRESS )
    {
        keys[key] = true;
    }
    else if ( action == GLFW_RELEASE )
    {
        keys[key] = false;
    }
}
}

   void MouseCallback( GLFWwindow *window, double xPos, double yPos )
     {
  if ( firstMouse )
{
    lastX = xPos;
    lastY = yPos;
    firstMouse = false;
}

GLfloat xOffset = xPos - lastX;
GLfloat yOffset = lastY - yPos;  // Reversed since y-coordinates go from 
  bottom to left

lastX = xPos;
lastY = yPos;
camera.ProcessMouseMovement( xOffset, yOffset );
    }
```

the Error exactly in 
       // Load models
       Model ourModel("res/models/nanosuit.obj");

Comment: Please post code and errors as text, not pictures.  Not everyone can see pictures.

Comment: [Just guessing here] A string literal in C++ is really an array of `const char`. It can decay to a pointer to that (i.e. `const char*`), but not a pointer to non-const `char` (i.e. `char*`).

Comment: Guessing from your error, you probably want to do this: `const_cast<GLchar*>(some_string_literal_here)`

Comment: What happens if you compile `int main(){char* p = "hello";}` on both compilers? If 2015 works and 2019 doesn't then @Someprogrammerdude is correct.

Comment: @Bathsheba yah it doesn't not work on 2019

Comment: And what about 2015 (assuming you still have the compiler)?

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't have it

Comment: You could share your code though. It's hard to suggest workarounds without seeing it. One could be to replace your string literal when constructing a `Model` with something like:  `char tmp[] = "<your string literal>"; auto x = Model(tmp);`.

Comment: So you binned the old compiler before checking if the new one compiled your code? Well, you won't do that again!

Comment: Did you try  `char tmp[] = "res/models/nanosuit.obj"; Model ourModel(tmp);` as I suggested?

Comment: The Error List reduces the amount of information given to make it fit more easily on the screen. This is great for simple problems, but when you "don't get it" switch over to the Output tab (it is down near the Error List). It often contains more complete information about the error and it is plain text, making it easy to paste into a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo yaah its work fine .. thank you

Comment: @DuaaAljamal You are welcome!. I'll put that up as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the model name as a non-const C string:

```
char tmp[] = "res/models/nanosuit.obj";
Model ourModel(tmp);
```